# Muting a website - UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Is there a way I can prevent a `UIWebView` from playing sound even if the website it is loading plays sound? I want to provide a mute feature in my custom browser.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/37315071/5251783

Answer (score 0):

Set these Parameters to your Webview

```
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

Please take a look at Apple Documentation [Link1](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617960-allowsinlinemediaplayback) [Link2](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617954-mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction?language=objc)